# How can I organise sharing the Internet bandwidth with many people at home?

Tags: qos, traffic-shaping

Lets say, you have a relatively fast Internet connection speed. However, there are many people who want to access the Internet and download files at the same time using that available bandwidth.

The problem is, even they can access the Internet at the same time due to NAT/PAT, since one of them use the entire bandwidth to download the files, the others will get slower speeds. Is it possible to distribute the bandwidth in a fair way?

Comment: Please include information about your router make and model. You may want to check its documentation to see if it supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Get or use a router that is compatible with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware.  It would be used to replace the firmware on your router.  It enables you to use QoS to limit individual computers to just a percentage of the total bandwidth.